# How to get notified when an embedded ActiveX control recieves and loses keyboard focus?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, activex, activexobject

I have a small C++/MFC dialog-based application with an embedded Internet Explorer ActiveX control. I want to know when that embedded control receives and loses keyboard focus. I thought to do this:

```
BOOL CWinAppDerivedClass::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    if(pMsg->message == WM_SETFOCUS)
    {
        //if(checkIEWindow(pMsg->hwnd))
        {
            //Process it
        }
    }

    return CWinApp::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

but no matter what I do, WM_SETFOCUS doesn't seem to be sent out at all.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use the process-wide [window procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644975%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) [hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

First you need to install the hook somewhere from the main thread of your GUI application. In case of an MFC dialog window the good location is the `OnInitDialog` notification handler:

```
//hHook is "this" class member variable, declared as HHOOK. Set it to NULL initially.
hHook = ::SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, CallWndProcHook, AfxGetInstanceHandle(), ::GetCurrentThreadId());
```

Then the hook procedure can be set up as such:

```
static LRESULT CALLBACK CallWndProcHook(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION) 
    {
        CWPSTRUCT* pCWS = (CWPSTRUCT*)lParam;

        //Check if this is the message we need
        if(pCWS->message == WM_SETFOCUS ||
            pCWS->message == WM_KILLFOCUS)
        {
            //Check if this is the window we need
            if(pCWS->hwnd == hRequiredWnd)
            {
                //Process your message here
            }
        }
    }

    return ::CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Also remember to unhook. A good spot for it is the `PostNcDestroy` handler:

```
if(hHook != NULL)
{
    ::UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
    hHook = NULL;
}
```